# Accessing JSON data that has no labels

Tags: javascript, json

```
var listCompleteInjections = [
    {"05-06-2014",0.5},
    {"16-06-2014",0.5},
    {"20-06-2014",0.5}
];
```

This is a fragment of data I am receiving from a device. It has only key and value but no labels to denote the same. I am unable to access the keys and values due to absence of labels. Please help.

**P.S.** the data corresponds to "Date" and "Dosage".

Comment: So you know the issue, what is your question?

Comment: Are you sure that is not `[
    ["05-06-2014",0.5],
    ["16-06-2014",0.5],
    ["20-06-2014",0.5]
]`?

Answer (score 3):

Given json is invalid.

Check [this jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)  or [jsonviewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)

Given string is not json so you can not read data.

If you have unknown key->value pair then also you can access json:

```
 var p = {
        "p1": "value1",
        "p2": "value2",
        "p3": "value3"
 };

for (var key in p) {
  if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    alert(key + " -> " + p[key]);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Hitesh- I used the code validated by JSONLint. Since javascript threw an exception, I had to tweak it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
for(var key in listCompleteInjections[0]) {
    console.log('Value: '+listCompleteInjections[key]);
}
```

You can also loop through your sub arrays like so:

```
for(var key in listCompleteInjections[0]) {
    for(var subKey in listCompleteInjections[key]) {
        console.log('Value: '+listCompleteInjections[key][subKey]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code snippet now is as below:
var text = '{\"listCompleteInjections\":[[\"05-06-2014\",0.5,[\"2114600271000185\"],\"0.50\",\"05 Jun 2014\"],[\"16-06-2014\",0.5,[\"2114600271000185\"],\"0.50\",\"16 Jun 2014\"],[\"20-06-2014\",0.5,[\"2114600271000185\"],\"0.50\",\"20 Jun 2014\"]]}';

var data = JSON.parse(text);

I am able to access the values for the key "listCompleteInjections". But only if I explicitly mention that name. This way i wil have to manually find out all the keys in the array and then use them to extract the values. is there a way to get the keys and subsequently its values?

Comment: If you check the edit you should get the general idea, it's hard to read your json the way it's laid out but it should work

Answer (score 0):

As Hitesh says, it's not valid JSON, but it's *almost* valid JSON.  I assume you're receiving this data as a string?  If so, you can massage it a bit with a `String.replace()` and a regex to *make* it valid.

```
var listCompleteInjections = '[\
    {"05-06-2014",0.5},\
    {"16-06-2014",0.5},\
    {"20-06-2014",0.5}\
]'.replace(/",/g, '":');
```

And now you can `JSON.parse()` it.

```js
function log(what) { document.getElementById('log').value += what + '\n'; }

var listCompleteInjections = '[\
    {"05-06-2014",0.5},\
    {"16-06-2014",0.5},\
    {"20-06-2014",0.5}\
]'.replace(/",/g, '":');

log('listCompleteInjections as massaged string:');
log(listCompleteInjections + '\n');

var obj = JSON.parse(listCompleteInjections);

log('obj[0]["05-06-2014"] = ' + obj[0]["05-06-2014"]);
```

```css
#log {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="log"></textarea>
```